# Route with distance marker for each Km. (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, route

In need to create a route from polyline where each Km in the route is identified.

This is what I did using the *create routes* tool:

[image]

This is the output from the tool:

[image]

I was expecting a listing with a unique ID for every 1Km segment.

Any help here.

Comment: Create a table with relevant chainages and compute route events or simply split line in editing mode and compute end points

Comment: @Felix, could you please develop your suggestions? I have knowledge of ArcGIS, but not really versed in routes/network analyst. Thanks.

Comment: @CindyJayakumar, Hi Cindy... I saw your question regarding routes, and It seems that you could help me with this simple issue, if you may of course. How can I add 1Km markers (or ID a given route every 1Km).? I believe is not hard to do, but I've tried and couldn't find a solution just myself. I need help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @ziggy, can you help me out here? If you could/may, thanks in advance!

Comment: The Create Route tool creates a PolylineM featureclass calibrated to the units you provide. Think of this as the network to create points or segments on top of using measure values rather that XY coordinates. As indicate by @FelixIP you create a [separate table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/linear-referencing/an-overview-of-creating-and-editing-event-data.htm) defining where you want your 1Km points to be along the route you just created and then display that.

Answer (score 1):

To do this outside of arcpy, I use excel to create a csv, then use the csv to create route events.

1. Add a route_id field to your line data and populate it with an id
2. Recreate the route using the route_id field as Route Identifier Field
3. Create a csv with the following columns: route_id, meas
4. Fill the entire route_id column with your route id
5. Fill the meas column starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 until you get to 75.  Add one more record for 75.246 (length of your route).
6. Run 'Make route event layer' using the csv as the input event layer.  Use route_id as the Route Identifier Field.

A less accurate but much quicker method is to create an empty point feature class, started editing the point feature class, select your route, click the editor drop-down menu, select 'Construct Points', set the distance to 1000 and tick 'Create start and end points'.  You'll have to manually set the KP for the endpoint to 75.246.  All the others will match the ROWID.

Also, if you don't need the KPs as a new feature class, you can simply display hatches every 1 km by going into the layer properties and going to the Hatches tab.

Comment: +1 for options, btw linear referencing might not work at all depending on how route was calibrated